# Pexpect ssh wrapper gracious quit and silent command

Tags: pexpect

I want to basically wrap interactive ssh, automatizing the login phase:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh ...')
child.expect('Pass prompt: ')
child.sendline(password)
child.expect('shell prompt> ')
child.sendline('cd /some/where')
child.interact()
```

This works. However, when the user then quits the shell (not using expect's control char), they get an exception (OSError).
My solution for this is:

```
    try:
        child.interact()
    except OSError as err:
        if err.errno == 5 and not child.isalive():
            # print 'Child exited'
            pass
        else:
            raise
```

Is there another cleaner solution ?

Also, I'd like to make the "cd /some/where" not echoed to the user. I tried with:

```
child.setecho(False)
child.sendline('cd /some/where')
child.setecho(True)
```

but with this the command is still echoed. Is there a more correct way to do, or is this a bug in setecho ?

Comment: Pexpect has [pxssh](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pxssh.html) specifically to wrap ssh for you. I don't know if it handles that situation any better, though.

Comment: You can make it a bit cleaner by reversing the if condition, so you don't need the else.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use [pxssh](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pxssh.html)
It handles all you need when spawning SSH process

See the code below:

```
import pxssh
import getpass

def connect():
        try:
            s = pxssh.pxssh()
            s.logfile = open('/tmp/logfile.txt', "w")
            hostname = raw_input('hostname: ')
            username = raw_input('username: ')
            password = getpass.getpass('password: ')
            s.login(hostname, username, password)
            s.sendline('ls -l')   # run a command
            s.prompt()             # match the prompt
            print(s.before)        # print everything before the prompt.
            s.logout()
        except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
            print("pxssh failed on login.")
            print(e)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect()
```